# How can you chose the kernel in Jupyter Notebook when executing with nbconvert script?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a python script that executes a Jupyter notebook. But every time it takes the default kernel, which is python3.
The relevant code line in the python script is this here:

```
os.system('jupyter nbconvert  --execute {:s} --to html'.format(IPYNB_FILENAME))
```

I have tried to change the default kernel in the jupyter_notebook_config.py file, but without success.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs [here](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute_api.html#execution-arguments-traitlets) it looks like you can do it like this:

```
jupyter nbconvert --ExecutePreprocessor.kernel_name=python3  --execute
```

etc

Comment: When I execute a `jupyter kernelspec list`
I get the following results:<br/>

   python37564bittensorflowconda21ecfdeab9d44a86aaede3520b26bb4c    C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\python37564bittensorflowconda21ecfdeab9d44a86aaede3520b26bb4c<br/>

  python3                                                          C:\Users\xxx\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\share\jupyter\kernels\python3<br/>
But this are not the kernels i have when starting the jupyter notebook from vscode.<br/>
Any ideas why i don't get the right kernels?

Comment: Oh, that's weird. But sounds like a VS Code issue. Maybe you should ask it as a separate question.

Comment: I will do, thank you very much. At least the first part of my problem was solved!