# Executing a Jupyter Notebook from the Command Line with a Specified Kernel

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, command-line

My goal is to use `jupyter execute ./file.ipynb` script in the command line but specify which kernel to run it with. Not sure how to do this, online keeps pointing me to nbconvert which I don't think I need. I will be running the script with an .sh file called run-notebook.sh which I activated via chmod.

Related question - do I need to activate my venv when running /User/Documents/run-notebook.sh?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73703189/8508004). `jupyter nbconvert` is getting used often behind-the-scenes when you use jupyter and so it is already installed and ready to go.